# How to parse Markdown anchor tags

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js, anchor

I'm using markdown to write a blog post.
It seems to parse the original text using some set or rules, like:

- space --> dash
- UpperCase --> lowercase
- special characters --> remove or ascii encoding

So, for a header like this:

```
# Hi, I'm José
```

I need to write a code like this:

```
[Click me](#hi-im-jos%C3%A9)
```

That's not so much intuitive. So, currently I need to:

- Create the header
- Generate the page
- Inspect the page
- Find the element
- Copy the href
- Paste into the anchor tag

What I wish:

- Create the header
- Somehow parse the header text to get the correct href
- Write the anchor tag correctly

I'm using [Nuxt.js Content](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get visibility on these anchors would be to add a hook in `nuxt.config.js`. That way you can can see the ids printed in your console without having to inspect the DOM element.

```js
{
  hooks: {
    "content:file:beforeInsert": document => {
      document.toc.forEach(item => {
        console.log(`${item.text} > #${encodeURI(item.id)}`);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Would output this in the console:

```
Hi, I'm José > #hi-im-jos%C3%A9
```